# Calculated type range

Tags: c++, types

Suppose I have the following

```
class X {
    typedef some_numeric_type my_type;
}
```

How to determine the limits of that `my_type`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) from the `<limits>` header.

```
#include <limits>

std::numeric_limits<my_type>::min()
std::numeric_limits<my_type>::max()
```

Comment: @OlegG, How about [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)?

Comment: @OlegG do you mean the code in the implementation, or how to use it? The implementation itself isn't mandated by the standard.